# Barcode Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, barcode

I have to create an Universal App for Windows Phone which uses Barcode scanner. I already used the BarcodeReader Class from Zxing in another non universal App, but now I have to go in this horrible world.

Any of you know how to use a barcodeReader App with Universal App?

I tryed searching on the net but the doc with this new world is really lacking..

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt426649.aspx

and sample : https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner

you need to use Windows.Devices.PointOfService namespace - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298071

Comment: I tryed using this namespace, but i don't have it. I downloaded the sdk from microsoft, but my POS reference doesn't have a BarcodeScanner class.. Any idea?

Comment: This is for bar code scanner peripherals. The question is about scanning from mobile.